# Should exporting a class make a difference?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-bug

```
class __declspec(dllexport) DI_1
{
    DI_1& operator = (DI_1 &){};
};

class DI_2
{
    DI_2& operator = (DI_2 &){};
};

int main()
{
    DI_1 a;
    DI_2 b;
    return 0;
}
```

The following code when compiled with `VS 2010/2012` gives the following error:

> error C4716: 'DI_1::operator=' : must return a value

whereas I was expecting it to return same error for `DI_2` class also.

Is this a compiler bug not flagging `DI_2` class also as an error?

If not, can anybody explain the reason?

Edit:
I confirmed with Solaris Compiler and it throws error for both classes.

Comment: The error is raised once you try to call b's `operator=`. However, technically it's only a compiler warning (which is automatically promoted to error). Not having a return is undefined behavior. Maybe dllexport imposes stricter rules.

Comment: Smells like a bug, post this to connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

Exporting class from the binary module should not make any difference. In your example I do not see any symantic difference either.

Nevertheless bad error reporting in incomparable less problem rather than the wrong code generation. Every reasonable compiler developer will follow this rule. This is the explanation.

p.s. During the template instantiation, only those methods that are called, are generated. Other methods (and potential syntax errors in them) are ignored. On the contrary, for classes AFAIK typically all methods are generated. I do not know good reasons for this asymmetry. Maybe MS compiler is doing something in this direction.